# Get courses chosen by all students

Tags: sql, database, relational-division

Now there are two tables **student(sid, name)** and **course(cid, name)**, which relation is many-to-many. So there is another table **student_course(sid, cid)** that stores the information about what courses have been chosen by whom.

How to write the sql that can get the courses that have been chosen by all the students?

Comment: ok no problem bro, it happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard solution: use the `NOT EXISTS ( ... NOT EXISTS (...))` construct:

- find all courses in which all students take part
- ==>> there **must not** exist a student that **does not** take part in this course

---

```
SELECT * FROM course c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * from student s
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * from student_course cs
                WHERE cs.sid = s.sid
                AND cs.cid = c.cid
                )
        )
        ;
```

This query is often faster (given appropiate indexes) than the `count() == count()` variant. The reason for this: you do not have to count **all** the (distinct) records; once you found **one** student that does **not** take *this* course you can omit *this* course from your *list of suspects*. Also: ANTI-joins often can make use of indexes [so can a count(), but that still has to count **all** the (distinct) keyvalues in the index]

Comment: I like my answer. However, I like yours better. It also performs much better when run through my same Fiddle. So have an up-vote

Answer (score 1):

```
Select c.cid, c.name 
From course c where 
(select count(1) from student) = (select count(1) from student_course sc where sc.cid = c.cid);
```

[See SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a7e00/4)

It finds all courses where the count of entries for that course in the student_course table matches the number of students

```
CID NAME
1   Test Course1
4   Test Course4
```